# Как передать cookies из сессии selenium в requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, selenium-webdriver, requests

Проблема встала с авторизацией в личный кабинет на auto.ru
Конечная задача собрать статистику по объявлениям за определенный период.
Когда аккаунт был один, то все решалось просто через VBA и авторизацию на auto.ru через IE

Но теперь аккаунтов стало несколько, и хотелось-бы автоматизировать процесс авторизации. Весть процесс авторизации обвещан ajax скриптами. Для авторизации через эти скрипты я использовал selenium-webdriver Firefox():

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    drv = Firefox()

    drv.get('https://auth.auto.ru/login/')
    try_count = 0

    """Авторизация через ajax скрипт"""

    while try_count < 10:   # Здесь ИНОГДА всплывает кнопка, которую нужно нажать что-бы продолжить 
        try:
            try_count += 1
            btn = drv.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="confirm-button"]')
            btn.click()
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            try_count += 1
            continue

    while True:
        try:
            login = drv.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/span/label/div/span/input')
            login.send_keys('**********', Keys.RETURN)
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue

    while True:
        try:
            password = drv.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[3]/span/label/div/span/input')
            password.send_keys('************', Keys.RETURN)
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
```

Это работает, в личный кабинет я захожу.
Дальше каким-то образом нужно передать сессию в requests.session для дальнейшей работы. И вот здесь как я понимаю нужно передать cookies в сессию requests.

выдача selenim `.get_cookies()` выглядит вот так:

```
[{'name': '_csrf_token', 'value': '62c6c12693832b221e370*****5744936e01c444d73d59', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False}, {'name': 'suid', 'value': '0c5da5698d907ef61f6ce776c0e95008.9109b8aa****b74b49d9f245095e466', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1604906256}, {'name': 'autoru_sid', 'value': 'a%3Ag5dc7b990*********32k7nllupd2npo.*************%7C1573370256112.604800.7jv-tw07xW7EdH***********51chKUv11gqj-vE6nwlcLv*********fiY6VM_E', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True, 'expiry': 1574579856}, {'name': 'autoruuid', 'value': 'g5dc7b990205vek9m432k7nllupd2npo.*********************', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True, 'expiry': 1574579856}, {'name': '_ym_wasSynced', 'value': '%7B%22time%22%*******%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22eu%22%3A0%7D%2C%22bkParams%22%3A%7B%7D%7D', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1573473937}, {'name': '_ym_uid', 'value': '1573370258208414976', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1604906257}, {'name': '_ym_d', 'value': '1573370258', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1604906257}, {'name': '_ym_isad', 'value': '2', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1573442258}, {'name': '_ym_visorc_22*******', 'value': 'b', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1573372058}, {'name': 'X-Vertis-DC', 'value': 'sas', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.auto.ru', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1573373858}]
```

Не могу сообразить как это корректно обработать, чтобы `requests` подхватил и продолжил сессию.

Comment: Не проще ли авторизироваться сразу через `requests`?

Comment: Вероятно, осталось только реквестом расковырять авторизацию Ajax. Если подскажете как, буду крайне признателен. (именно вон ту, что на auto.ru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю автоматизировать авторизацию с помощью `requests`.

---

```py
import requests


def login_with_password(login: str, password: str) -> requests.sessions.Session:
    """Авторизация для старых аккаунтов, где используется связка логин+пароль
    :param login: Логин (email или телефон) для авторизации
    :type login: str
    :param password: Пароль для авторизации
    :type password: str

    :return: Авторизованная сессия
    :rtype: requests.sessions.Session
    """
    session = requests.Session()

    # Получаем CSRF токен в cookies для дальнейшей работы
    response = session.get('https://auth.auto.ru/login/')

    # Дублируем CSRF токен из cookies в заголовок x-csrf-token,
    # чтобы не передавать его вручную при каждом запросе
    CSRF_token = response.cookies['_csrf_token']
    session.headers.update({"x-csrf-token": CSRF_token})

    json_for_login = {
        "items": [
            {
                "path": "auth/login",
                "params": {
                    "login": login,
                    "password": password
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    # Авторизируемся
    session.post("https://auth.auto.ru/-/ajax/auth/", json=json_for_login)

    return session # Возвращаем авторизованную сессию


def login_with_email(email: str) -> requests.sessions.Session:
    """Авторизация для новых аккаунтов, где используется связка почта+код с почты
    :param email: Email для авторизации
    :type login: str

    :return: Авторизованная сессия
    :rtype: requests.sessions.Session
    """
    session = requests.Session()

    # Получаем CSRF токен в cookies для дальнейшей работы
    response = session.get('https://auth.auto.ru/login/') 

    # Дублируем CSRF токен из cookies в заголовок x-csrf-token,
    # чтобы не передавать его вручную при каждом запросе
    CSRF_token = response.cookies['_csrf_token']
    session.headers.update({"x-csrf-token": CSRF_token})

    json_for_code = {
        "items": [
            {
                "path": "auth/login-or-register",
                "params": {
                    "email": email
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    # Отправляем серверу запрос, чтобы он отправил
    # нам почту email 6-ти значный код
    session.post("https://auth.auto.ru/-/ajax/auth/", json=json_for_code)

    # Тут любым образом достаёте этот код с почты
    # ...

    json_for_login = {
        "items": [
            {
                "path": "user/confirm",
                "params": {
                    "email": email,
                    "code": "666666" # 6-ти значный код с почты
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    # Авторизируемся
    session.post("https://auth.auto.ru/-/ajax/auth/", json=json_for_login)

    return session # Возвращаем авторизованную сессию
```

Comment: добавил html, посмотрите плз. Очень хочется избавиться от этого паровоза в виде selenium. Но что-то не выходит. Хотя-бы алгоритм подскажите. код я сам наклепаю, а то затык какой-то

Comment: @Andey Уфф... Ну сейчас попробую ещё на часик заморочиться...

Comment: Добавил апдейт в вопрос

Comment: @Andrey Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Andrey Немного подправил код. Теперь заголовок `x-csrf-token` не надо отправлять каждый раз вручную.