# requests.Session() не работает корректно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
oyorooms_session = requests.Session()
response = oyorooms_session.get('https://www.oyorooms.com/')
CSRF_token = response.cookies['_csrf']
print(CSRF_token)
oyorooms_session.headers.update({"XSRF-TOKEN": CSRF_token})
oyorooms = oyorooms_session.get('https://www.oyorooms.com/api/pwa/generateotp?phone='+ phone_number[1:] +'&country_code=%2B7&nod=4&locale=en')
print(oyorooms.text)
```

В выводе дает это:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Значит не хватает каких-то заголовков/куки, что не так в коде?

Сам запрос:

```
GET /api/pwa/generateotp?phone=номер телефона&country_code=%2B7&nod=4&locale=en HTTP/1.1
Host: www.oyorooms.com
Connection: close
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
XSRF-TOKEN: rqHX94QY-_CrOnGut6aK5s0U-le56ydHOOck
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 YaBrowser/19.10.3.281 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: https://www.oyorooms.com/login?country=&retUrl=/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _csrf=NeffO9F41obAZZ31t3UzMbzj; acc=IN; mab=122a651fd09d4974150c1b2e6fbb170b; expd=j%3A%7B%22mwen%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%225%22%7D%2C%22phbb%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22shel%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22weng%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%224%22%7D%2C%22bann%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22sold%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22otp4%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%22dwep%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22a2hs%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%22aowt%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%225%22%7D%2C%22mww2%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%224%22%7D%2C%22brch%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22hbad%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22dwhp%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%225%22%7D%2C%22pppp%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A0%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D%2C%22BnTc%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%22mwql%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%22ndlp%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%225%22%7D%2C%22near%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%22mnlp%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%223%22%7D%2C%22hind%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%223%22%7D%2C%22bcpw%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%22gmmw%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%22clbn%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%223%22%7D%2C%22ioab%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%22mhdp%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%220%22%2C%22v%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%22ndpp%22%3A%7B%22val%22%3A%221%22%2C%22v%22%3A%221%22%7D%7D; _uuid=dUxaRnA5NWJyWFlQYkpQNnEtemo6bzdvX01KLUNFbnRyS3hfdEgyLUE%3D; _uid=Not%20logged%20in; XSRF-TOKEN=rqHX94QY-_CrOnGut6aK5s0U-le56ydHOOck; connect.sid=s%3ABCbEgZjgkVzDYZF7yutqIsUfI8JhpbTp.n1PGdsm7f1tzThaWuC8YmVTerq%2BpYBRNhAZe61tbsCI; fingerprint2=068fbb97e4140ddb5a00e21fbe94a286; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; _ga=GA1.2.317067115.1574962872; _gid=GA1.2.1585307640.1574962872; _gat=1; tvc_heatmap=enabled; _gat_gtag_UA_52365165_1=1; cto_lwid=34d54d93-794d-4b67-9c8b-34a112bfbea7; tvc_sm_lpc=direct%7Cnone%20/%20undefined; tvc_clicksInfo=/login?country=&retUrl=/|3
```

Comment: Вот здесь посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044398/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-cookies-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-selenium-%d0%b2-requests

Comment: А вообще обращение к API подразумевает как минимум использование ключа API

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что проблема только в `cookies`? Возможно, не хватает каких-то заголовков.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Вполне возможно, изменил название вопроса.

Comment: @Tayrus Сравните "рабочий" и "нерабочий" запросы, попробуйте поизменять что-нибудь, поубирать и т.д., пока из "нерабочего" не получите "рабочий".

Comment: Судя по тому, что Вы пытаетесь передать данные формы в url, попробуйте в запрос POST добавить заголовок `Content-Type=x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @Andrey тут же везде GET запросы, куда добавлять?

Comment: Боюсь ошибиться, @МихаилМуругов точнее вас сориентирует в этом вопросе, но мне кажется что этот `oyorooms = oyorooms_session.get('https://www.oyorooms.com/api/pwa/generateotp?phone='+ phone_number[1:] +'&country_code=%2B7&nod=4&locale=en')` запрос должен быть `post`

Comment: Я отслеживал трафик (запрос прикрепил к вопросу) и там GET запрос

Comment: @Tayrus У Вас есть пример "рабочего" запроса?

Comment: Да, под текстом 'Сам запрос:"